# Simple property not found?

Tags: jsp-tags

What is solution for `simple property not found,jodd bean bean exception`?

Moreover data doesnt get inserted into Database

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
11:20:59,247 ERROR [http-bio-28080-exec-11][BeanPropertiesImpl:337] jodd.bean.BeanException: Simple property not found: hId Invalid property: 'heighttableImpl#hId' (actual:'heighttableImpl#hId', forced=false)
jodd.bean.BeanException: Simple property not found: hId Invalid property: 'heighttableImpl#hId' (actual:'heighttableImpl#hId', forced=false)
    at jodd.bean.BeanUtilBean.getSimpleProperty(BeanUtilBean.java:158)
    at jodd.bean.BeanUtilBean.getIndexProperty(BeanUtilBean.java:250)
    at jodd.bean.BeanUtilBean.getProperty(BeanUtilBean.java:482)
    at jodd.bean.BeanUtil.getProperty(BeanUtil.java:111)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the method/line of code on which this exception is thrown? Also, while you're editing, you could [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the exception message as a quote so we can clearly see which part of the question is question and which part is exception message. Thanks.

Comment: but this error comes from another table that i dont use

Comment: Aha. That would have been worth mentioning in the question.

Comment: so what should i do? i need help

Comment: I still think you should edit your question to include your code. Presumably *some* of the code is yours - could you post the relevant bits of that? Maybe see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you go do so - the act of reducing your problem down will make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no simple property `hId` in the class `heighttableImpl`. Can you show us the source of this class?

Property has to be accessible in that class and optionally to have the getter, in order to be read.